# Plotly Select Values from Dropdown menu

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, plotly

i have a dataset pm looking like this :

```
        DATE    Method   Amount D     Amount W
0   20220509    m1       34482.57     0.00
1   20220509    m1       15109.53     12.00
2   20220509    m2       908.83       0.00
3   20220510    m3       5526.90      0.00
4   20220511    m3       0.00         1885.94
........................ ............ ......
```

I am using the code below to create a line chart for each value selected by a dropdown menu

```
fig=px.line(pm,x='DATE',y="Amount D",color="Method")
maps=pm['Method'].unique().tolist()
methods=[]
vis=[]
visList=[]
for m in maps:
    for col in pm.columns:
        if col == m:
            vis.append(True)
        else:
            vis.append(False)
    methods.append(m)
    visList.append(vis)
    vis=[]
buttons=[]
for i , g in enumerate(methods):
    button=dict(label=g,
               method='restyle',
               args=['visible',visList[i]])
    buttons.append(button)
buttons=[{'label':'all',
         'method':'restyle',
         'args': ['visible', [True]]}] + buttons

# update layout with buttons                       
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
        type="dropdown",
        direction="down",
        buttons = buttons
)
    ],
)
fig.show()
```

All i get is a plot with all the values but when i try to select one specific value from the dropdown i get an empty chart.
Question one : How can i create dynamicly a plot by selecting each value from the dopdown
Question two : Is it possible to create a plot with two lines using column AmountD and Amount W ,for each value by selecting it from the drop down menu

Answer (score 0):

- have simulated a dataframe that is same structure as your sample
- building drop-down menus in **plotly** is about consistency.  I know the documented examples always show **for** loops with `append()` to lists.  IMHO it's far simpler to be consistent with list comprehensions
- below shows how to build the drop-down using list comprehensions

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

pm = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.DataFrame(
            {
                "DATE": pd.date_range("20220509", periods=20).strftime("%Y%m%d"),
                "Method": [m for _ in range(20)],
                "Amount D": f(np.linspace(0, 6, 20)),
            }
        )
        for m, f in zip(["m1", "m2", "m3"], [np.sin, np.cos, lambda x: x / 6])
    ]
)

fig = px.line(pm, x="DATE", y="Amount D", color="Method")

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": m,
                    "method": "update",
                    "args": [
                        {
                            "visible": [
                                True if m == "All" else t.name == m for t in fig.data
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                }
                for m in ["All"] + pm["Method"].unique().tolist()
            ]
        }
    ]
)
```